# Make a div draggable on multi touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-touch

I'm trying to make an HTML element draggable on multi-touch.

I though jQuery UI's `.draggable()` function would do it, but that only work on desktop devices not on multitouch.

**How can I make an HTML draggable only on the X axis with javascript and / or jQuery ?**

If there is a way to make it only draggable in the right direction and not to the left, that would be great as that is exactly what I am looking for.

How would one do this in javascript ?

I was looking at Hammer.Js, but that listen for gestures on elements. How do I make an element follow a gesture to act as if it is moving along with the gesture, when it is going right, and  the gesture is directly manipulating or controlling its position?

Answer (score 0):

Try Pep.Js it does kinetic dragging for multi-touch and point-and-click devices.

Here is a demo of it in action: http://codepen.io/briangonzalez/pen/fdf7b7a6e981fc1079d202ddefeb375c